# Controlling order of display in ipywidgets Vbox (when matplotlib widget is used)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

This is so damn irritating... using:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) [GCC 9.3.0]
matplotlib 3.5.0
ipywidgets 7.6.5
jupyter 1.0.0
```

So, consider this example:

```py
import IPython.display
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout

%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widget_01 = widgets.HTML("<p>Hello, world</p>")
widget_02 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))
widget_03 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))

with widget_02:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    display(widgets.HTMLMath("<p>Try equation: $x_y = y_x$</p>"))
    
myvbox = widgets.VBox([
    widget_01,
    widget_02,
    widget_03
],)
display(myvbox)

with widget_03:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    display(widgets.HTMLMath("<p>In the next episode...</p>"))
```

So, I have a "Vbox", which has three elements, "widget_01", "widget_02", "widget_03"; these three elements are put in a list, which (unlike dict) has an order, so I can count on "widget_01" being "first", "widget_02" being "second", and so on. And since this is a "VBox", that is, Vertical Box, I'd expect the "first" item in the list to be rendered on top, the "second" item below it (that is, in the middle), and so on.

And indeed, that is how the output looks like in the simplest case:

[image: vbox_order_ok]

Ok, cool - now, let's just make "widget_02" into `matplotlib widget`:

```py
import IPython.display
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout

%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widget_01 = widgets.HTML("<p>Hello, world</p>")
widget_02 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))
widget_03 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))

with widget_02:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,1), dpi=90)
    fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2])
    
myvbox = widgets.VBox([
    widget_01,
    widget_02,
    widget_03
],)
display(myvbox)

with widget_03:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    display(widgets.HTMLMath("<p>In the next episode...</p>"))
```

Well, now - for whatever reason - "widget_02" (which became a plot) is not in the middle anymore, but is instead last (at bottom):

[image: vbox_order_bad]

I mean, I sure *update* "widget_03" after I update the plot - but I'd expect the VBox to keep the order of widgets?

So - how can I have a Matplotlib widget rendered in the order it is listed into an ipywidgets VBox, *even* if I update a different widget in the same VBox after I have rendered the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution here: [Displaying a previously created Matplotlib figure in a widget · Issue #203 · matplotlib/ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/203), it seems ...

The problem turns out to be not so much "controlling placement" *per se*, but:

- The fact that `fig = plt.figure...` call actually produces output by itself, regardless of (`with`) output context; that can be prevented with disabling matplotlib interactive mode via `plt.ioff()`
- The fact that to display an interactive matplotlib widget, we should `display(fig.canvas)` (not just `display(fig)`)

So, in the OP, there was not even a `display(fig)` - so the entire output of the matplotlib widget was due to the `fig = plt.figure...` call.

Therefore, to obtain the desired output, as specified in the VBox (widget_01 text on top, widget_02 plot in middle, widget_03 text on bottom):

[image: vbox_layout_ok]

... the following corrected code can be used:

```py
import IPython.display
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout

%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widget_01 = widgets.HTML("<p>Hello, world</p>")
widget_02 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))
widget_03 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))

with widget_02:
    widget_02.clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.ioff() # "turn off interactive mode so figure doesn't show"
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,1), dpi=90)
    fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2])
    plt.ion() # "figure still doesn't show"
    display(fig.canvas) # "It's the canvas attribute that is the interactive widget, not the figure"
    
myvbox = widgets.VBox([
    widget_01,
    widget_02,
    widget_03
],)
display(myvbox)

with widget_03:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    display(widgets.HTMLMath("<p>In the next episode...</p>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `plt.show()` after `ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2])` solves your issue for me.
See code below:

```py
import IPython.display
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widget_01 = widgets.HTML("<p>Hello, world</p>")
widget_02 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))
widget_03 = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))

with widget_02:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,1), dpi=90)
    fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2])
    plt.show()
    
myvbox = widgets.VBox([
    widget_01,
    widget_02,
    widget_03
],)
display(myvbox)

with widget_03:
    IPython.display.clear_output(True)
    display(widgets.HTMLMath("<p>In the next episode...</p>"))
```

And the output looks like that:[image]

Comment: Thanks - I was a bit surprised that does indeed work as shown on the screenshot; but taking a closer look, you did not use `%matplotlib widget` directive, and therefore the plot rendered in your solution is just an image, it's not interactive. If you look at the solution I came to, that one preserves the interactivity of the matplotlib widget.

Comment: That's a good point. I removed it because the  `%matplotlib widget` line crashes on my google colab and on my jupyter notebook.