# Download SVG of plot from `%matplotlib widget` in Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, jupyter-notebook

Say, I have a code like this in a Jupyter notebook (like in [Controlling order of display in ipywidgets Vbox (when matplotlib widget is used)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097421/controlling-order-of-display-in-ipywidgets-vbox-when-matplotlib-widget-is-used)):

```py
import IPython.display
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout

%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widget_out = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='100%'))

with widget_out:
    widget_out.clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.ioff() # "turn off interactive mode so figure doesn't show"
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,1), dpi=90)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2])
    plt.ion() # "figure still doesn't show"
    display(fig.canvas) # "It's the canvas attribute that is the interactive widget, not the figure"

myvbox = widgets.VBox([
    widget_out,
],)
display(myvbox)
```

It results with a rendering like this:

[image: matplotlib widget toolbar]

Now, when I click the "Download plot" button, I immediately get a download dialog for a "Figure 1.png" file:

[image: download dialog png]

..., and there is no obvious option I could change, so I could obtain a different format - and here I'd want .svg.

When I use the usual Matplotlib from Python on dekstop however, and I click the "Save the figure" button there, there is actually a picker for file formats:

[image: save the figure formats]

... and .svg is there.

Is there a way to persuade `%matplotlib widget` inside Jupyter to "save as" .svg (or other vector format), instead of .png?